# Pipe connection between Python and C# in two directions - sending data

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, pipe

I have a huge problem with connection between my `python` script and `C#` WFA application.
For some reason the code worked two days ago last I checked and today when I started the script the connection is not establishing which is very odd.

So below is my C# code connection:

```
                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
                    {

                        // Create a named pipe server
                        NamedPipeServerStream server = new NamedPipeServerStream("mypipe");

                        // Wait for a client to connect
                        server.WaitForConnection();

                        // Send data to the client
                        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello from C#!");
                        server.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                        // Disconnect from the client and cleanup resources
                        server.Disconnect();
                        server.Dispose();
                    });
                    t.Start();

                    this.Close();
                    Application.Exit();
                }
```

Here is my python code that is calling the C# application:

```
        # Run the C# subprocess in parallel
        p = subprocess.Popen(['C:/Users/.../source/repos/UI_Variables_Prompt/UI_Variables_Prompt/bin/Debug/UI_Variables_Prompt.exe', str(calculation_tool)])

        p.wait()

        # Connect to the named pipe server
        client = win32file.CreateFile(r'\\.\pipe\mypipe', win32file.GENERIC_READ | win32file.GENERIC_WRITE, 0, None, win32file.OPEN_EXISTING, 0, None)


        # Receive data from the server
        data = win32file.ReadFile(client, 4096)[1].decode('utf-8')
        print(data)

        # Disconnect from the server and cleanup resources
        win32file.CloseHandle(client)
```

The `calculation_tool` variable is succesfully being sent to C# but that is all, when I click `confirm button` i.e. start this case `if (result == DialogResult.Yes)` in `C#` the process is freezing and It seems that the data is not being sent.

I am struggling with this for two hours, and I can't seem to find a solution, please help.

Thank You in advance!

EDIT:

```
p.wait() in your Python code will wait until the process 
terminates. The process can't terminate until it has communicated,
 but it can't communicate because the Python is waiting. 
You do NOT want p.wait() there. – 
    Tim Roberts
```

This is right, however without `p.wait()` python tries to communicate with a non-existing pipe, because the C# process terminates before it can establish a connection.

```
client = win32file.CreateFile(r'\\.\pipe\mypipe', win32file.GENERIC_READ | win32file.GENERIC_WRITE, 0, None, win32file.OPEN_EXISTING, 0, None)
pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

EDIT 2:

It worked with `try-except` instead of `p.wait()` **BUT** how can I change the code so the pipe will be connected so the user won't have to wait a couple of seconds for the app to connect - because on first try it always throws back the same error I posted above.

```
# Connect to the named pipe server
        connected = False
        while not connected:
            try:
                client = win32file.CreateFile(r'\\.\pipe\mypipe', win32file.GENERIC_READ | win32file.GENERIC_WRITE, 0,
                                              None, win32file.OPEN_EXISTING, 0, None)
                connected = True
                print('Connected')
            except:
                print('Failed to connect to named pipe, retrying in 5 seconds...')
                time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: `p.wait()` in your Python code will wait until the process terminates.  The process can't terminate until it has communicated, but it can't communicate because the Python is waiting.  You do NOT want `p.wait()` there.

Comment: @TimRoberts    Oh, right, but without it is also problematic, because, without `p.wait()` python will try to connect to the not existing server/pipe `pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')`